# Intel realsense cam on win 7

Tags: windows-7, camera, codec, realsense

Did anyone successfully used an intel realsense camera on windows 7?
The intel SDK won't work, the open source drivers do, but there is no
windows codec for the color stream. Depth streams are working nice.
Did anyone manage to find a way to get this work?

Comment: What's the version of the SDK?

Comment: I got an update, SDK won't work, but the librealsense does work. Color stream is limited to full HD, but it's runnable on win7 and any intel cpu [not only the 5+gen]